# How can I place a one-column-abstract in a two-column document with lyx

Tags: lyx

i use elsarticle template with lyx  (document ->settings->document class ->Elsevier )

and i want to prepare an artcile in two column model

how can I place a one-column-abstract and after that two-column-section in a  elsarticle template with lyx?
thank you

Comment: cross-posted at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/352664/how-can-i-place-a-one-column-abstract-in-a-two-column-document-with-lyx. Please read http://latex-community.org/home/latex-community/94-etiquette/454-crossposts and think about why cross-posting without referencing the other posts can be impolite to those who would like to spend their time to help you.

Comment: hi ,thnak you for your remarque ,but i posted my question 3 days before and when no one answer me i reposted in other way here and in other site because i nedded  the answer and i googled for a long time and i ddin't find my answer ,sorry

Comment: I understand, but did you read the post I asked you to? It doesn't say you can't cross-post. It explains why it is important to reference your other posts.

Comment: hi, I read again, but I still didn't know what I did wrong exactly, what I should reference ?

Comment: Thanks for making an effort to understand. In the future, you should provide a link from each of your posts to each of the other posts. Does it make sense how that can solve the problem of duplicated effort?

Comment: ok , next time i will, i understnad now